# How to get all the native methods that have been called with gdb?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I have a program I want to debug. I would like to get all native methods that are called without setting any breakpoints, since the program I run exhibit a weird behavior and skip compiling the methods it is supposed to do.

Is there a way to have all native methods that have been called by a java program with `gdb` (without setting breakpoints) ?

Comment: what do you mean by native methods?